# Deploying application from behind a local proxy using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, proxy, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a ruby on rails app using Capistrano. Both my development machine and server are behind a proxy. I'm not having trouble using a proxy on the remote machine (which is what majority questions involving a proxy and Capistrano are about).

When Capistrano executes the command `run_locally` it doesn't keep any of the environment variables set from my bashrc. How do I set the settings for Capistrano when it runs commands locally? Commands like `executing locally: "git ls-remote https://github.com:user/project.git master` fail.

deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require "capistrano-rbenv"
load 'deploy/assets'
require 'creds.rb'
set :rbenv_ruby_version, "1.9.3-p484"
set :rbenv_repository, "https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git"

set :application, "visio"



# Deploy from your local Git repo by cloning and uploading a tarball
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "https://github.user/project.git"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :branch, "master"
set :rails_env,     "production"


set :user, :deploy
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false

set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
default_run_options[:pty] = true

role :web, "10.9.43.153"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "10.9.43.153"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "10.9.43.153", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

# ensure http_proxy variables are set
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH",
  'BASH_ENV' => '$HOME/.bashrc',
  'https_proxy' => 'https://proxy.org.local:8080',
  'http_proxy' => 'http://proxy.org.local:8080'
}

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post your deploy.rb file here to have a look!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
default_run_options[:env] = {
    'http_proxy' => '192.168.1.10:8080', #Your HTTP proxy server
    'https_proxy' => '192.168.1.10:8080', #Your HTTPS proxy server
    'HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI' => 'false',
}
```

it worked for me.

source: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/using-proxy-capifonycapistrano

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and revert back.

Comment: Where have these lines to be added?